# Xcode Buttons, Images Disappearing

Tags: xcode, uiview, storyboard

Has anyone else out there had problems with elements of their storyboard disappearing? The most recent instance: I disabled `Highlighted Adjusts Image` on a button and the next thing I know everything in my view controller disappears EXCEPT for my background `UIImage`.  So this included a label, a `UIImage` with a responder attached, and two buttons.  I switched to the newest version of `XCode` but that did not bring back MY GUMDROP BUTTONS :(

I have rebuilt my view about 4 times now and it's getting old... Any thoughts? Thanks.

Comment: maybe you can post the code you implement.

Answer (score 0):

Wow do I feel like an ass.  I don't know if this was the problem every time BUT somehow my damn elements were placed "beneath" my UIImage background element. I opened up my Document Outline and wouldn't you know somehow my background image jumped up above all of my other elements (top of the list beneath the parent view)...and I'm posting this only minutes after posting my initial question.  I feel dumb...happy holidays!

Answer (score 0):

Go check the background from View Controller Sense and remove it. Your button and whatever was in storyboard will appear right away.